# Borrar texto de una cadena

Tags: java

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
String cadena = "El usuario pepito@gmail.com ha activado su cuenta con pepito@gmail.com"
```

Me gustaria eliminar el @gmail.com pero no puedo hacer un replace de eso porque podria ser cualquier otro servidor de correo(hotmail.yahoo,etc)

```
Opcion 1 => no válida para otros servidores de correo
cadena = cadena.replaceAll("@gmail.com", "")

Opcion 2
String regex = "/\\@[\\w\\.-]+/g";
message = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(message).replaceAll("")
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si no añades lo que has hecho o intentado no podemos ayudarte. En SO no hacemos los deberes a nadie, por lo que, si no añades nada nuevo, tendré que votar negativamente tu pregunta.

Comment: Si pongo la duda es porque no se como hacerlo, es posible que con expresiones regulares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que si puedes hacer el replace pero usando una expresión regular.

```
String cadena = "El usuario pepito@gmail.com ha activado su cuenta con pepito@gmail.com"
```

Solución:

```
cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\\@[\\w\\.-]+", "")
/* Debe reemplazar cualquier texto que inicie con @, seguido de cuaquier letra, numero, punto, _ o - */
```

Puedes validar la expresión regular aquí con distintos casos https://regex101.com/r/HMhFsp/1

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Probe esto pero me borra toda la cadena
cadena= cadena.replaceAll("[/\\@[\\w\\.-]+/g]", "")

Comment: Intenta copiarlo exactamente de esta manera. `cadena= cadena.replace(/\@[\w\.-]+/g, "")`

Comment: de esa forma no me compila, he añadido a mi post original otra forma de hacerlo pero no funciona

Comment: Oh, claro, he asumido que era _javascript_ hahahaha

Comment: haciendo esto me remplaza cada palbra por bb message.replaceAll("[/\\@[\\w\\.-]+/g]", "bb")

Comment: Vale, ahora entendiendo que es Java. ¿Ya probaste de esta manera `cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\\@[\\w\\.-]+", "")`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116266/discussion-between-cajotafer-and-sirdaiz).

Comment: Gracias me funciona tu respuesta

Comment: ¡Genial! lamento la confusión al inicio. Editaré la respuesta principal para que esté correcta.